# php global variable not showing correct answer

Tags: php, function, variables, global

Its very simple code but i don't understand whats the point :(

```
function aaa($b){
$a = 30;
global $a,$c;
return $c=($b+$a);}
echo aaa(40); //Output is 40
```

Why the output is 40 ? When i call the $a outside of function it gives me the desired answer so what the point ?

```
$a = 30;
function aaa($b){
global $a,$c;
return $c=($b+$a);
}
echo aaa(40); //Output is 70


function aaa($b){
global $a,$c;
$a = 30;
return $c=($b+$a);
}
echo aaa(40); //Output is 70
```

Comment: That is because [Global variables are never the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527)

Comment: $global will not work any more in PHP 5.4+ - thank's god, the sh.. is gone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See what the `global` keyword stands for here:

```
function aaa($b) {
    $a = 30;               # local variable, will be overwritten just in the next line
    global $a, $c;         # importing $a from the global scope - NULL
    return $c = ($b + $a); # $c = (40 + NULL)
}
```

The manual at http://php.net/global reminds that a global variable influences the function if it is used inside there. That is not only for the first call but also for all subsequent calls.

This makes the function non-deterministic, so less useful code and you might - as you just did - get irritated by it.

An easy way out is: Instead of putting parametric values of that function into global variables, turn them into parameters:

```
function aaa($a, $b, &$c) {
    return $c = ($b + $a);
}

echo aaa(30, 40, $c); //Output is 70
```

The code is not only much easier to read but also *deterministic*. It will always behave the same when called. That means less guessing.

This example still has the problem of returning a value by a parameter (by reference), however you might see as well that this is not really necessary any longer:

```
function aaa($a, $b) {
    return ($b + $a);
}

echo $c = aaa(30, 40); //Output is 70
```

Lessons to take away:

- Do not use global variables inside functions - they only stand in your way.
- Reduce the number of parameters a function has (that are about *all* incomming values, so global counts as well).

Comment: So if i define a variable before global(within func), it will be NULL ?

Comment: No, `$a` is NULL because in the global scope it is NULL (by default in PHP all unset variables are NULL). `global $a` in the function tells PHP to use `$a` from the global scope inside the function. Therefore the once local variable now has the value from the global variable (NULL).

Comment: Also you should not wonder only why this does happen here, but also follow a much more important question: Why do you *need* a global variable here?

Comment: Yeah i know that, when to use `global` variable but i got that question within a mocktest and after that i posted that question.

Answer (score 1):

When using for example `global $a;`, PHP overwrites the variable `$a` and assigns to it a reference, as if this statement is replaced by:

```
$a = &$GLOBALS["a"]; // and the same with every other variable which is used in global
```

And as `$a` isn't defined in your first example, `$GLOBALS["a"]` evaluates to `null` and so `$a` is becoming a reference to a variable holding a `null` value.

Try to `var_dump($GLOBALS);` after and before the function call. It will show you a new index named `a` after the function call (with the value `null` or the value you've assigned it to).

(P.s.: In reality it's doing a direct reference to the variable in the main scope.)

Answer (score 0):

```
in php a variable Scope priority is 
 1- local variable
 2- global variable
```

even you determine global $a in function body but local variable $a used when it apear.
   refer to [Php variable reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)
if you want use global variable with same name of your local variable you must user 
   $GLOBALS['c']=$GLOBALS['a']+$b;   if $c and $a is global definition
hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I think, in first case $a is undefined. First write value of $a then call function. Use error_reporting(E_ALL) at top of page to know errors in script.

Comment: Even `$a` is undefined in the global scope, the global keyword does define it in the local scope so you won't see that warning.